Why am i getting "Channel is unrecoverably broken and will be disposed!" error, trying to load large images in recycler view
I have a gallery fragment in my Android TV App with horizontal recyclerView where i`m trying to show images loaded with Coil (they might have a large size like 10mb, 20mb etc.). The requirement is that image should fill the fixed size of the list and then "crop" horizontally to its size.
Im getting an error: "Channel is unrecoverably broken and will be disposed!" and my app crashes while I'm trying to scroll quickly through recycler to the right and then to the left and so on.
Here is my fragment:
class ImageGalleryFragment : Fragment() {

    private val navArgs by navArgs<ImageGalleryFragmentArgs>()
    private val viewModel: ImageGalleryViewModel by viewModels {
        ImageGalleryViewModelFactory(
            requireContext(),
            navArgs.movieId,
            navArgs.materialId,
            navArgs.isExclusive
        )
    }

    override fun onCreateView(
        inflater: LayoutInflater,
        container: ViewGroup?,
        savedInstanceState: Bundle?
    ): View {
        val binding = FragmentImageGalleryBinding.inflate(inflater, container, false)

        viewLifecycleOwner.lifecycle.addObserver(object : DefaultLifecycleObserver {
            override fun onCreate(owner: LifecycleOwner) {
                val imagesAdapter = ImageGalleryAdapter(lostFocus = {})

                with(binding) {
                    rvImages.adapter = imagesAdapter
                    rvImages.addItemDecoration(
                        LinearHorizontalSpacingDecoration(
                            requireContext().resources.getDimension(
                                dimen.list_grid_small_item_horizontal_margin
                            ).toInt(),
                            true
                        )
                    )
                    ivBack.setOnClickListener { findNavController().popBackStack() }
                    subscribers(imagesAdapter)
                }
            }

            override fun onResume(owner: LifecycleOwner) {
                viewModel.onEvent(Event.SendAnalyticsOnPageOpened)
                super.onResume(owner)
            }

            override fun onDestroy(owner: LifecycleOwner) {
                binding.rvImages.adapter = null
            }
        })

        binding.ivBack.doOnLayout {
            binding.ivBack.requestFocus()
        }

        return binding.root
    }

    private fun FragmentImageGalleryBinding.subscribers(
        imageGalleryAdapter: ImageGalleryAdapter
    ) {
        viewModel.state
            .map { it.materialName }
            .flowWithLifecycle(viewLifecycleOwner.lifecycle)
            .distinctUntilChanged()
            .filterNotNull()
            .onEach { updateView(it) }
            .launchIn(viewLifecycleOwner.lifecycleScope)

        viewModel.state
            .map { it.imageAssets }
            .flowWithLifecycle(viewLifecycleOwner.lifecycle)
            .distinctUntilChanged()
            .filterNotNull()
            .onEach { imagesList ->
                imageGalleryAdapter.submitList(imagesList)
            }
            .launchIn(viewLifecycleOwner.lifecycleScope)
    }

    private fun FragmentImageGalleryBinding.updateView(galleryName: String) {
        tvGalleryName.text = galleryName
    }
}

Here is my adapter:
class ImageGalleryAdapter(
    private val lostFocus: () -> Unit,
) : ListAdapter<ImageAsset, ImageGalleryItemViewHolder>(DiffUtils()) {

    class DiffUtils : DiffUtil.ItemCallback<ImageAsset>() {

        override fun areItemsTheSame(
            old: ImageAsset,
            new: ImageAsset
        ): Boolean = old.url == new.url

        override fun areContentsTheSame(
            old: ImageAsset,
            new: ImageAsset
        ): Boolean = false
    }

    override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int) = ImageGalleryItemViewHolder(
        ItemGalleryImageBinding.inflate(
            LayoutInflater.from(parent.context),
            parent,
            false
        ),
    )

    override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: ImageGalleryItemViewHolder, position: Int) {
        holder.onBind(item = getItem(position))
    }
}

Here is my viewHolder:
class ImageGalleryItemViewHolder(
    private val view: ItemGalleryImageBinding,
) : RecyclerView.ViewHolder(view.root) {

    fun onBind(item: ImageAsset) {
        with(view) {
            ivImage.load(item.url) {
                crossfade(true)
                crossfade(250)
                placeholder(R.drawable.ic_gallery_image_placeholder)
            }
        }
    }
}

And here is my itemView xml:
<androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatImageView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/ivImage"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:adjustViewBounds="true"
    android:focusable="true"
    android:foreground="@drawable/foreground_focusable_transparent_stroke_3dp"
    android:scaleType="fitCenter"
    tools:src="@tools:sample/backgrounds/scenic" />

After searching for some similar issues I found that it might be some problems related to scaling large images in recycler, but I tried to replace any scale with fixed size, but it doesn't seem to be working.
I'd be glad to have any help or suggestions with this issue.
